# Why does SJCL report "this is not JSON" when trying to decode this JSON snippet?

Tags: json, sjcl

I'm using [SJCL](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/), and it works fine with small ASCII strings.

But when I try to decode [this piece of JSON](https://gist.github.com/2499251) (the result of the encryption of an HTML page) I get a `"this is not JSON!"` error.

**The JSON has been produced by SJCL**, and while I did encode it and decode it using LZW and base64 I don't get this error for small strings with the same workflow.

I tracked the error message origin to the [decode function](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/SJCL/blob/master/core/convenience.js#L167). I assume the regexes are failing but I don't understand why as this seems to be a perfectly formed JSON string to me.

However, I can be wrong as if I do a JavaScript eval on it it fails on a syntax error. But if I dump it in a file Python parse it fine.

Comment: That link to SJCL is broken. http://crypto.stanford.edu/SJCL/ I have no idea what SJCL is, I thought it was a typo for `JCL` when I saw the tag. This is the first instance of an SJCL tagged question on SO, by the way!

Comment: I just saw `Analysis of the Python tag Stackoverflow activity` - yɛlɛman http://yeleman.com/analyse-of-the-python-tag-stackoverflow-activity/ presume it to be yours. It is rather awesome!

Comment: Thanks, Yes it is my article :-) I also ported some SO answers about metaclass, decorators et yield to my website. But I fail to update it as much as I'd like to.

Comment: @feral ok I fixed the link to sjcl. It's a javascript implementation of an encryption framework. It's pretty fast while not very big in size.

Comment: e-sat Cool! Thank you. I just hailed the CHorror, enclosed a link to your Giant Python post. It needs to be seen. The spinning gray circle thingy was an especially nice bit of finesse.

Comment: Arg, I'm not just my little wordpress website would survive if 1% of the readers of CHorror clic on the linK. But thanks for the gesture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I made a double passed base64 encoding. One before encryption, and one after. It seems that removing the first pass make it work.

Answer (score 4):

The json that is at your `this piece of json` link starts and ends with a double-quote character. Is that actually part of the contents of the json? If it is, I believe that is your problem. Otherwise, it looks like valid json to me.

Comment: agreed - I took your snippet, replaced the outer " with ', stuffed it into a variable in firebug, and used jQuery.parseJSON() on it. Worked fine.

Comment: Not, the double quote are not part of the json. I paste the string representation in the ghist.

Comment: Ok I removed the quotes to avoid the misenderstanding. But I'm betting now somebody will thell me this is not json but a javascript object :-)

Comment: In my case I needed to `JSON.parse` first and then `JSON.stringify`